# Database IAM authentication failing from Google Dataflow instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Python based application that is using Apache beam in batch mode and Google Dataflow as a worker.

The first step of my pipeline is to read data from a database table as input PCollection. The library that I have used as Input connector requires DB build-in user and password (not IAM user) and first step is getting executed successfully.

Now, in second step, I want to update the DB rows (just 1 right now for testing) to IN_PROGRESS. Here, I am using an IAM user which I am also using outside of Dataflow. But  I am getting an error in dataflow pipeline -

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "xx.xx.xxx.xx", port 5432 failed: FATAL: AlloyDB IAM user authentication failed for user "{iam_user}".
```

I also tried creating a new IAM user corresponding to the service account I am using for workers and provided it with the same permissions as the IAM user outside of dataflow. But ,I am still seeing the same error. From logs, I can see DB IP ,DB name and IAM users are correctly being passed.

Is there anything additional that I should be doing for an IAM user to successfully connect to DB?

Comment: Can you try again after giving the following roles alloydb.databaseUser and serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer? You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/manage-iam-authn#console).

Comment: Those roles are already there and as I have mentioned, the same IAM user can connect to same DB from outside of dataflow

Comment: Hi@Sumit Desai, It seems like a permissions issue. Have you checked the [logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface)?

Comment: Yes, it looks like dataflow does not support IAM users. It's working fine with a DB built in user which uses password for authentication